# Symfony3: validate nested (optional) forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

i have three documents in my project: Event, OrganizerProfile and User.

Users can have multiple OrganizerProfile (it's like 'pages' on Facebook) and Events.

When a User creates and Event, he can assign an "OrganizerProfile" to the event (User Alberto creates an event for "Company A" that's called "Event X").

To achieve this, i've created this forms:

**OrganizerProfileType.php**

```
class OrganizerProfileType extends AbstractType{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextType::class, ['required' => false])
...
```

**EventType.php**

```
class EventType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $profileChoices = ... //List of existing profiles

        $builder
            ->add('profile_list', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $profileChoices,
                'required' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
            ])
            ->add('profile', OrganizerProfileType::class, [
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('title', TextType::class, ['required' => false])
            ->add('description', TextType::class, ['required' => false])
...
```

In the field "profile_list" users can find their existing OrganizerProfiles. Users can pick one of them and assign it to the event BUT if the user doesn't pick an existing profile he must insert information in the "profile" form.

I'd like to make "optional" the profile form and make it required only if the users don't pick an existing profile.

How can i do this? Thanks

Comment: You can [Choose Validation Groups Based on the Submitted Data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement by [Validation Groups Based on the Submitted Data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html).

So your FormType should be as follow:

```
class EventType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $profileChoices = [...];

        $builder
            ->add('profile_list', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => $profileChoices,
                'required' => false,
                'mapped'   => false,
            ])
            ->add('profile', OrganizerProfileType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new Valid()
                ]
            ])
            ->add('title', TextType::class, ['required' => false])
            ->add('description', TextType::class, ['required' => false]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {

                if (null === $form->get('profile_list')->getData()) {
                    return ['without_profile'];
                }

                return ['with_profile'];  // Or simply 'Default'
            },
        ]);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE: Use the validation group in the other FormType also**

Then you need to handle the validation of the subform with the validation group, as example:

```
class OrganizerProfileType extends AbstractType{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotNull(
                            [
                                'groups' => ['without_profile', 'with_profile']
                            ]
                        )
            ]])
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotNull(
                            [
                                'groups' => ['without_profile', 'with_profile']
                            ]
                        )
            ]])
            ->add('description', TextType::class, ['required' => false])
```

Hope this help

Comment: thanks, i'll try your solution tomorrow! If it will work i'll offer you a beer at the SymfonyDay (if you will be there ;) )

Comment: If i put validation groups in the "Event" document, when i reach the "$form->isValid()" method it stops correctly, but he totally skips the validation of OrganizerProfile forms, ignoring the validation group. I've also tried with 'cascade_validation', but it's still not working. It only works with a "manual validation" (using the validation service and validating the OrganizerProfile form with the right group). Is there a way to validate all forms (and sub-forms) with the standard method "$form->isValid()"?

Comment: hi @AlbertoFecchi, you should Use the validation group in the other FormType also. Check my Update. Hope to see you to the sfday also :)

Comment: Ok, i found the solution! I should use a "Valid()" constraint instead of "NotNull()" in the EventType form (or directly in the Event document using annotations: @Assert\Valid). Now my code works! If you update your answer i'll mark it as the best answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: hi @AlbertoFecchi happy you find a solution!  answer updated

Comment: just one more correction: Valid constraint doesn't accept 'groups' parameters, new Valid() is enough !